# Бесплатная распределённая база данных с открытым исходным кодом с интерфейсом для языка С

Tags: c, база-данных

Интересно поработать с распределенной базой данных на чистом С бесплатно (в т.ч. для коммерческого использования). Какие есть хорошие DDB с открытым исходным кодом? Есть ли возможность интегрировать БД и Glade?

Comment: Мне кажется, что приведённым формулировкам неплохо удовлетворяет DNS :)

Comment: Можно ссылку на проект, если речь о БД?

Comment: Sqlite, амальгаматион модель.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MySQL Cluster is the distributed database combining linear scalability
>   and high availability. It provides in-memory real-time access with
>   transactional consistency across partitioned and distributed datasets.
>   It is designed for mission critical applications.
>
> MySQL Cluster has replication between clusters across multiple
>   geographical sites built-in. A shared nothing architecture with data
>   locality awareness make it the perfect choice for running on commodity
>   hardware and in globally distributed cloud infrastructure.

https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/

- Бесплатная
- С открытым кодом
- С интерфейсом для "С"